# python socket on 2 difrent pc not connecting

Tags: python, sockets, chat

```
def server():
        import socket
        s = socket.socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        x = socket.gethostname()
        host = socket.gethostbyname(x)
        print(" server will start on host : ", host)
        port = 1024
        s.bind((host,port))
        print("")
        print(" Server done binding to host and port successfully")
        print("")
        print("Server is waiting for incoming connections")
        print("")
        s.listen(1)
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print(addr, " Has connected to the server and is now online ...")
        print("")
        while 1:
            message = input(str(">> "))
            message = message.encode()
            conn.send(message)
            print("message has been sent...")
            print("")
            incoming_message = conn.recv(1024)
            incoming_message = incoming_message.decode()
            print(" Client : ", incoming_message)
            print("")


def client():
        import socket
        from socket import AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
        x = socket.gethostname()
        info = socket.gethostbyname(x)
        print("yours user is: " + info)

        s = socket.socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        host = input(str("Please enter the hostname of the server : "))
        port = 1024
        s.connect((host,port))
        print(" Connected to chat server")
        while 1:
            incoming_message = s.recv(1024)
            incoming_message = incoming_message.decode()
            print(" Server : ", incoming_message)
            print("")
            message = input(str(">> "))
            message = message.encode()
            s.send(message)
            print("message has been sent...")
            print("")
```

Comment: please format your code

Comment: You can format by placing \`\`\`python before the code and \`\`\` after. Also please ask a question and tell what happens when you run the code with what input, and what you expected to happen.